# Update a single table based on data from multiple tables in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
UPDATE ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N aen
SET aen.gmcid = (
        select
            lm.gmcid --,lm.gmlid,lm.cost_center,aen.client_name,cm.client_name,aen.customer_account
        from customer_master cm
        inner join location_master lm on  cm.gmcid =lm.gmcid
        inner join ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N aen on  lm.cost_center=aen.cost_center
            --and lm.cost_center='1405FC0505'
                  )
FROM ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N aen
JOIN location_master lm ON lm.cost_center=aen.cost_center
JOIN customer_master cm ON cm.gmcid =lm.gmcid;
```

SQL compilation error: duplicate alias 'AEN'
--WHERE lm.cost_center='1405FC0505';

Comment: Um... you've aliased ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N 3 times all as AEN... once in an update, twice in froms, one in an subquery, one in the main.  yeah... you're going to get conflicts.  Adjust so you're not using the same alias.  Really onlyu thing you need to fix the  Update or from one... the subquery should be fine as it runs in isolation so long as there's not correlation.

Comment: Could you please able to rewrite the query

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would help and let us test our responses.

Answer (score 0):

**UNTESTED:**    My guess w/o any way to validate.

This should resolve the alias error: I make NO comments regarding the actual update statement working.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do,

- aen to Uaen when used in the update.
- aen to subaen when used in a subquery

..Giving us...

```
UPDATE ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N Uaen
SET Uaen.gmcid = (
        select
            lm.gmcid --,lm.gmlid,lm.cost_center,subaen.client_name,cm.client_name,subaen.customer_account
        from customer_master cm
        inner join location_master lm on  cm.gmcid =lm.gmcid
        inner join ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N subaen 
           on  lm.cost_center=subaen.cost_center
            --and lm.cost_center='1405FC0505'
                  )
FROM ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N aen
JOIN location_master lm ON lm.cost_center=aen.cost_center
JOIN customer_master cm ON cm.gmcid =lm.gmcid;
```

Maybe.... you mean...

**UNTESTED:**

```
UPDATE ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N Uaen
   SET Uaen.gmcid = lm.gmcid
  FROM ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N aen
 INNER JOIN location_master lm 
    ON lm.cost_center=aen.cost_center
 INNER JOIN customer_master cm 
    ON cm.gmcid =lm.gmcid;
```

Comment: 1st update-Single-row subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: 2nd is executing but not giving expected output

Comment: I have 3 table.. ACCOUNTING_ENTITIES_N.. its main table.. here i have a field gmcid which is null which i am trying to update.. by referencing location_master  lm.cost_center=aen.cost_center and 3rd is customer_master referencing cm.gmcid =lm.gmcid; so from all this 3 table i am trying to match cost_center from lm and cm, then taking gmcid from cm table and update in aen table.. i hope its understandable now..

Comment: and this is why a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is needed.  Sample data; expected results.  I can't guess at what you're trying to do.  Well... I can guess.. but you can see I'm not very good at it.

Comment: As a long time member you know SO is a great site to [ask GOOD questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and get answers: Just be sure to provide a complete [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Before you ask a question consider [talking to the duck first](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/). Yes, I'm serious! To help us help you, generate sample data and expected results. [ascii table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) makes the output easy to read! You could also mock up data and the SQL tried using http://rextester.com/ or a similar site.